# How to read from app.config - LibraryConfigUtilities

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

How to read values like culture etc. from the app.config file below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="LibrarySetting" type="LibraryConfigUtilities.ConfigurationSectionHandler, LibraryConfigUtilities" />
  </configSections>

  <LibrarySetting>
    <Country Culture="tr-TR" Currency="TRY" DailyPenaltyFee="5,25" PenaltyAppliesAfter="3">
      <WeekendSetting>
        <Weekend Day="6"/>
        <Weekend Day="0"/>
      </WeekendSetting>
      <HolidaySetting>
        <Holiday Date="25.11.2009"/>
        <Holiday Date="26.11.2009"/>
        <Holiday Date="27.11.2009"/>
      </HolidaySetting>
    </Country>
    <Country Culture="ar-AE" Currency="AED" DailyPenaltyFee="8.00" PenaltyAppliesAfter="4">
      <WeekendSetting>
        <Weekend Day="5"/>
        <Weekend Day="6"/>
      </WeekendSetting>
      <HolidaySetting>
        <Holiday Date="25.11.2009"/>
        <Holiday Date="26.11.2009"/>
        <Holiday Date="27.11.2009"/>
      </HolidaySetting>
    </Country>
  </LibrarySetting>
</configuration>
```

I have below code in my program. And i want to read values from the above app.config.

```
private List<Country> settingList = new LibrarySetting().LibrarySettingList;
```

and i added

```
using LibraryConfigUtilities;
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using `ConfigurationManager.GetSection("LibrarySetting");`

See if this will help get you anywhere.

Use this link as a reference, has some good help. [App Config Group Help](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16466/Unraveling-the-Mysteries-of-NET-2-0-Configuration#sectiongroups)